# How can I make the header just display in one line?

Tags: html, css

I need to make the name etc. displaying in one line. I tried out `display: inline;` on the "header" but it didn't work. (im newbie)

```css
body {
  background-color: snow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.611rem;
}

header .circle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.79rem;
  width: 1.79rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

header .circle__red {
  background: #ff605C;
}

header .circle__yellow {
  background: #FFBD44;
}

header .circle__green {
  background: #00CA4E;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="circle circle__red"></div>
    <div class="circle circle__yellow"></div>
    <div class="circle circle__green"></div>

    <div class="name">
      <h3 class="name-alt">Muhammed Ali Yuruk</h3>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Code:
https://codepen.io/saruhankaya_/pen/rNpGMxK

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` on the children of header not header. The selectors `header>*` or `.circle, .name` should work.

```css
body {
  background-color: snow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.611rem;
}

header .circle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.79rem;
  width: 1.79rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

header .circle__red {
  background: #ff605C;
}

header .circle__yellow {
  background: #FFBD44;
}

header .circle__green {
  background: #00CA4E;
}

header>* {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="circle circle__red"></div>
  <div class="circle circle__yellow"></div>
  <div class="circle circle__green"></div>

  <div class="name">
    <h3 class="name-alt">Muhammed Ali Yuruk</h3>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using flexbox as suggested buy several other is probably the best way to go

*Buuuuut*

The quickest / easiest method:

```css
.name { display: inline-block; }
```

Additional you will need to remove the margin off the heading tag or it wont appear to be inline.

```css
.name-alt { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

- Debatable if you need the `<h3` since you force the font size so I made it a `div`
- You can use flex display and set this to display in a row with `flex-direction`.
- How you align or space out can be set several ways, here I used the column gap but margins some such or a `space-between` to get them scattered on the row evenly.
- I removed some of the CSS since it was not the best way for the circles perhaps and really gives the same thing this way.
- You did not specify how it should handle small/narrow screens so I let it wrap (line long text etc. might be in play here)

```css
body {
  background-color: snow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  column-gap: 0.25em;
}

header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.611rem;
}

header .circle {
  height: 1.79rem;
  width: 1.79rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

header .circle__red {
  background: #ff605C;
}

header .circle__yellow {
  background: #FFBD44;
}

header .circle__green {
  background: #00CA4E;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="circle circle__red"></div>
    <div class="circle circle__yellow"></div>
    <div class="circle circle__green"></div>
    <div class="name">
      <div class="name-alt">Muhammed Ali Yuruk</div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: I know that you know it but: `flexbox` is not needed here but ok to sue same as `inline`/`inline-block`. `flex-direction: row` and `align-items: flex-start` is not needed either as both are the default values for thsoe properties and are redundant as such.

Comment: I made the example explicit for clarity.  Debatable on the `inline-block` due to the wrap characteristics so I noted that. So given that, not totally "the same" here.

Comment: Like I said, I know that you know it. Also aware that you just did it for eplaination purpose. See my comment as an added info that you not specifically need to declare those properties as they are the default behavior in the first place, not a critic.

Comment: I would point out that using `flexbox` has the side effect that, in case of long wrapping text, it keeps the indentation regarding the circles, whereas `inline/inline-block` will flow the text under the circles. Keeping the indentation might be a desired effect that could not be obtained with inline flow.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look too long at this but using flex-box it would look like this.

```
header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.611rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You need to apply the display attribute to the parent container - in this case the header since it contains the h3 and the div icons.

Then align-items will center it on the opposite axis, the y-axis in this case since the default direction is on the x-axis (flex-direction: row).

Answer (score -1):

I agree that `display: flex;` would be a simple solution. Using `flex-wrap: nowrap;` will prevent content from shifting to the next line.

```
header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.611rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```